# Cheking memory with valgrind with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

tring to make a script what checks is there was a memory leaks or tried to access bad memory

was tring this script
but without luck cuz when the prog compiled with warnings, the valgrind gives me "BAD" status, even thats no mem leaks present

```
#!/bin/bash
#some varibles for the future
output=${1}
progname=${2}
input=${3}
trash="/dev/null"

# execute the prog and putting output to out file
valgrind --error-exitcode=1 ./${progname} < ${input} >${output} 2>&1

# grab exit status of valgrind (0 if all good ,1 if not)
ret=$?

# write appropriate message as per return status value
((ret == 0)) && echo "Memory V" || echo "Memory X"

# return the exit status of testMemory
exit $ret
```

I thought maybe some code like this

```
# cheking for patters that indicate err
#if [[ grep "ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors" "$output" ]] # >"$trash" 2>&1
#then
#   ret=0
#else
#   ret=1
#fi


any ideas?
```

Comment: "cuz when the prog compile with warnings it gives me "OK" status" - wat? you don't even compile in your script...

Comment: In the second script shown, why do you search for the error patterns in the "$input" file? I think you should do that in the "$output" file.

Comment: yes you right but still not working..

Comment: Please, might you post some examples of the "ERROR SUMMARY" lines reported by the valgrind command?

Comment: If your program exits with non-zero, even if there are no Valgrind errors, Valgrind will return non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

i just did it this way
i hope it will check all the errs

```
#!/bin/bash

#some varibles for the future
output=${1}
progname=${2}
input=${3}
trash="/dev/null"

# execute the prog and putting output to out file
valgrind ./${progname} < ${input} >${output} 2>&1
# cheking for patters that indicate err
grep -q "ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors" "$output"

# grab exit status of grep (0 if all good ,1 if not)
ret=$?

# write appropriate message as per return status value
((ret == 0)) && echo "Memory V" || echo "Memory X"

# return the exit status of testMem
exit $ret
```